# OpenGL - Draw two textures using the same FBO?

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo

How can I draw two textures using the same FBO?

As seen bellow, I have a `initDesktop()` where I initialize my both textures (previously loaded using SOIL). 
On my other class, I want to execute the `drawDesktop()` which will draw my background rectangle with a texture, and a footer rectangle...

I only see the footer...
What I am missing here?

**EDITED**

```
void Desktop::initDesktop ()
{
    GLuint fboId = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId);

    //now with GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_background.getId(), 0);

    //now with GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_footer.getId(), 0);
}

void Desktop::drawDesktop ()
{
    drawBackground ();
    drawFooter ();
}

void Desktop::drawBackground ()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0); //<-- ?
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 1200, 800, 0, 0, 1200, 800, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

}

void Desktop::drawFooter ()
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1); //<-- ?
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 1200, 100, 0, 0, 1200, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just draw textured quads… much easier and less hassle. Yes I am aware that you have to setup a shader for that. So what…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to attach two textures to the same attachment point:

```
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_background.getId(), 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_footer.getId(), 0);
```

the latter call will override the former one. So you have the footer texture bound to this FBO. To fix this, you can attach both textures to different attachment points, like `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` and can use 
[`glReadBuffer()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadBuffer.xhtml) to select which one `glBlitFramebuffer()` will read from. Don't confuse the currently selected read and draw buffers with the currenlty bound read and rsw framebuffers. These are different concepts. Drawing will always go into the currently selected drawbuffer(s) of the currently bound `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, and read operations on the color buffer source the pixel data from the currently selected read framebuffer of the currently bound `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Another option would be to just attach one texture at a time, and switch between them. Or even using two FBOs. But switching the read buffer alone is probably the cheapest.

Comment: Thanks @derhass :) How can I use the `glReadBuffer()` to select the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` for example? like this: `glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1)`?

I've seen some examples using the `GL_NONE` and `GL_BACK`, but it is unclear how can I switch between the color attachments

Comment: When an FBO is bound,  valid values for `glReadBuffer` are the `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT`i enums, so this is straight forward.

Comment: I'm still getting only one texture:/. I'm using like this:
`void Desktop::drawBackground ()
{
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
 glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
 glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 1200, 800, 0, 0, 1200, 800, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
}

void Desktop::drawFooter ()
{
 glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
 glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
 glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, 1200, 100, 0, 0, 1200, 100, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
}`
I'm binding as you said...but it is still not working:(